# Android Activity.getParent() always returning null

Tags: android

I have this little function here:

```
public Activity getRootActivity()
{
    Activity a = this;
    while (a.getParent() != null)
        a = a.getParent();
    return a;
}
```

But a.getParent() always returns null.  It doesn't seem to matter how deep into my UI I go, it will always return null.

Anybody have any idea as to why?

**EDIT**

Here is how I am starting Activities (within other activities)

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, activityname.class));
```

Apparently that means I'm not 'embedding' them? How does one 'embed' them?

Comment: right. a becoming null is not a problem, only a.getParent() returns null.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Documentation says: public final Activity getParent ()
Since: API Level 1

Return the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.

Is your Activity an embedded child?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, because initially `a != null`  and it can't become null due to while loop condition.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by 'embedded child'.

Comment: The most common case of embedded activities are members of an ActivityGroup. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

Comment: @Nikita. He is reassigning a with each step of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

[`Activity#getParent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent%28%29):

> Return the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.

Is the activity an embedded child? If not, `getParent()` will return null.