# Intent crashing when trying to navigate to Previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Basically, I don't know why, but when I try to go from one activity to the previous one ( using ym back button)
 the intent is null, therefore null pointer exception.

The way I do the intent is:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Puzzle_Activity.this, Play_Activity.class );
    startActivity(intent);
```

and there's nothing wrong with that code as far as I know.
yet the logcat is giving me

```
 04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.angrywordsearch/com.example.angrywordsearch.Play_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.example.angrywordsearch.Play_Activity.onCreate(Play_Activity.java:60)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-24 19:23:15.074: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  ... 11 more
```

So what I'm asking is; Why is it null if I specify the classes to go to?

Play activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Intent Newintent = getParent().getIntent(); // Line 60
        Bundle extras = Newintent.getExtras();
        if(Newintent.hasExtra("userName"))
        {
            userName =  extras.getString("userName");
            Password = extras.getString("Password");
        }
            setContentView(R.layout.play_layout);       

    }
```

Comment: show your `onCreate()` in `Play_Activity`

Comment: Line 60 :   Intent Newintent = getParent().getIntent();

Comment: Which version of Android? (to be able to look at the right ActivityThread.java)

Comment: We know the Intent expected is null, the problem is you don't return any Intent when coming back to this activity, Intent is always null unless you set a value for it.

Comment: 4.2 api 16 + as far as i know

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Activity.getParent() always returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102772/android-activity-getparent-always-returning-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `getIntent()` instead of `getParent().getIntent()`,  `getParent()` is probably null.

`getIntent()` gives you the intent that the activity was started with.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says:

`public final Activity getParent ()` Since: API Level 1

Return the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.

Is your Activity an embedded child?