# Android How to invoke action to UI thread

Tags: java, android

Currently, I'm trying to download some contents from Web and would like to push it to ListView:

I created a Runnable to do the download content part:

```
Runnable postTest = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL u = new URL("192.168.1.1/getList.php");
            ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
            c.put("token", networkCommunication.getToken());
            String k = networkCommunication.downloadContent(u, c);
            getParent().runOnUiThread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(Main.this, k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

The code works fine until `String k = networkCommunication.downloadContent(u, c);`

But then, the "K" variable is not accessable in "Run" method, also, I tried changing the k variable to "Hello world" (i.e. print hello world when it finish downloading the content) but then another exception occurs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because getParent() is NULL. According to the documentation:

> public final Activity getParent () Since: API Level 1
>
> Return the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.

You can refer to this similar question : [Android Activity.getParent() always returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102772/android-activity-getparent-always-returning-null)

Comment: Oh I removed the getParent(). and the problem solved! I can now access the "K" variable